# Pandas: Merging Sorted Dataframes

Tags: pandas, numpy, sorting, pytables, chunking

I have a large (Nx4, >10GB) array that I need to sort based on col.2.

I am reading my data in chunks and sorting using Pandas. But I am unable to combine the sorted chunks to give me a **final large Nx4 array that is sorted on Col.2**. I want this process to be as fast as possible as well. Here is what I have tried yet:

```
chunks = pd.read_csv(ifile[0], chunksize=50000, skiprows=0,
                     names=['col-1', 'col-2', 'col-3', 'col-4'])

for df in chunks:
    df = df.sort_values(by='col-2', kind='mergesort') # sorted chunks
    print(df)
```

Comment: One idea, that I'm not sure about the interest, can you only load the second column (not by chunk, the full data at once), sort and then use the sorted index to load your data by chunk?

Comment: @Ben.T: I was doing that before. I used numpy's argsort and trace the index. Though that worked for small/medium files. I faced memory issues for files large as 1-10 GBs. So, I was recommended to use chunking. Again, I intend to make it as fast as possible without overloading my memory. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I think this is a perfect usecase for `Dask` see https://examples.dask.org/dataframe.html